# Give an example of a skew–symmetric2×2–matrix B with entries in C for which I2+B is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples

Give an example of a skew-symmetric $2\times2$ matrix $B$ with entries in $\mathbb C$ for which $I_2+B$ is not invertible.

[image]

I'm struggling with this Lin Algebra problem if you could help me with it that'd be great. Thank you.

Comment: The condition that B is 2×2 confines the scale of this problem, whereas the restriction that B is skew-symmetric transform it into a single-variable problem.  Please show us your work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put two concepts together: 1. what is a skew symmetric matrix? and 2. When is a matrix not invertible? The answer for 1 is a matrix of type $$B=\begin{pmatrix}0 &b\\ -b&0\end{pmatrix}$$
The answer for 2 is $$\det(I_2+B)=0$$
Calculate explicitly this determinant, and see when it is $0$.

Comment: +1 for stating more clearly what I intended.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** (1) A skew symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix has entries $a,b,-b,a$

(2) $I_2$ has entries $1,0,0,1$

(3) A square matrix is not invertible if and only if its determinant is zero

Comment: I thought that skew symmetric matrices have $A_{ij}=-A_{ji}$, therefore $A_{ii}=0$

Comment: @Andrei : Yes, that's true. So always $a=0$. Hmm, I see I have listed the entries in the wrong order, my bad, will correct. Thanks.